# Drupal- hook_block_view show block for user created nodes

Tags: drupal, hook, block, nodes

I am trying to add a hook_block_view  to a module. Right now, the hook allows the block to show on all nodes that the user DID NOT create. Why? There has to be something wrong with my code.

What I want is the opposite to whats going on. I want the hook to allow the block to show on ONLY the nodes that the user created.

```
function instantblocks_block_view($delta) {
  //Add JS and CSS if the user has admin access to this block
  if (instantblocks_access('any block controls', NULL, $delta)) {
    instantblocks_load_files();
  }

  $block = array();

  $content = instantblocks_block_view_content($delta = '');

  if (preg_match('#node/([0-9]+)#', $_GET['q'], $matches)) {
              if ($node = node_load($matches[1])) {
                global $user;
                if ($user->uid !== $node->uid) {

    $block['content'] = array(
      '#type' => "markup",
      '#markup' => '<div class="instantblocks">' . $content . '</div>',
    );

  }
  }
  }

  return $block;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I do have the me alias module installed that turns all UID's to the users alias. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Nope. me alias module has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code specifically says

```
if ($user->uid !== $node->uid)
```

So, if the user isn't the one who created the node, they see the block content (unless I am missing something). Changing that to

```
if ($user->uid == $node->uid)
```

should solve the problem.